# PHP | 502 Ошибка Bad Gateway

Tags: php, phpstorm

Делая очередной метод для сортировки массива, при отладке браузера вдруг внезапно появилась ошибка "502 Bad Gateway PhpStorm 2016.3".
Интерпретатор php 5.6 на месте, не пойму в чем дело. Сижу, паникую.
Раньше такого не было.

Comment: Стандартное перезапустить PphStorm/комп пробовали?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, отключен вывод ошибок.
Первыми строчками в скрипте попробуйте добавить

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

После этого сервер должен выдать подробное описание ошибки.

Comment: ну или залезть в файл логов и там узреть ошибку

Answer (score 0):

Вроде бы как [есть такая ошибка в phpstorm 2016](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17317/502-Bad-Gateway-error-from-the-server-when-post-data). И вроде бы ее поправили.
Возможно стоит обновить версию phpstorm.